# How do I retrieve incident work items from BMC Remedy ARS via the SOAP interface?

Tags: soap, remedy

I'm using the Helpdesk_Query_Service method from the HPD_IncidentInterface web service in BMC Remedy ARS 7.5 to retrieve incident data. I can get the top-level incident data as expected, but I don't see any way to retrieve associated work items. The ITSM Integrations guide is extremely light on details. How do I get the work items out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create webservice for the form where the data is. **Ie** if the work item information is in the form HPD:WorkLog then you will need to create a webservice for this form.

Once the webservice has been created (and you've mapped the fields across) you can begin consuming it. The webservice will also appear on your list of webservices.

I am not 100% sure but the Remedy 7.5 out of the box installation does not have allot of ready-made webservices.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was rather hoping that there'd be something out of the box that would do it as our Remedy admins aren't particularly keen building/installing anything non-standard.

Comment: This is true. Have you tried looking at the BMC Remedy .Net API? It allows you to query forms directly without the need of a web service. Latest version is 7.6.4

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm not using .Net here so its not immediately applicable, but perhaps I can study it and steal its lucky charms :)